# Creating random patterns of image objects with specified minimum distance between them and random orientation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

This is my first time using stackoverflow and I hope some of you guys will help me solve this issue.

I'm designing a psychophysics experiment that requires random display patterns as shown here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n09vkvbqxagt8hd/dot%20pairs.png?dl=0

However, still I need to specify several remaining parameters, but I don't know how:

1. Each object (imported image of dot pairs) needs to be randomly distributed but to retain minimum, non-overlapping distance from any other object and the edges of the background rectangle.
2. Each object (image of dot pairs) has to have a random orientation.

I hope someone will help me with the addition of the two parameters under 1 and 2 as soon as possible!

Thank U!

The code I found, adapted, and used to generate the illustration given here is (there are 9 images, each made of dot pairs, named with "stim"*.png):

```
import random
import pygame

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0  ,0  ,0  )

class Player():

def __init__(self, image, x=0, y=0):

    self.image = pygame.image.load(image) #.convert()
    #self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    self.rect.centerx = x
    self.rect.centery = y

#------------

def draw(self, screen):
    screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

#------------

def update(self):
    # here change randomly positon
    self.rect.topleft = random.randint(60,220+1), random.randint( 0, 475+1)

class Game():

def __init__(self):

    pygame.init()

    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

    self.background = pygame.image.load("background.jpg").convert()
    self.multi_players = []

    # create stimuli

    for i in range(1,10):
        player = Player("stim"+str(i)+".png")
        player.update() # set random position on start
        self.multi_players.append(player)

#------------

def run(self):

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    RUNNING = True

    while RUNNING:

        # --- events ---

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                RUNNING = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    RUNNING = False

                # changes position when key is pressed

                for player in self.multi_players:
                    player.update()

        # --- updates ---- 

        # place for updates

        # --- draws ---

        self.screen.fill(BLACK)

        self.screen.blit(self.background, self.background.get_rect())

        for player in self.multi_players:
            player.draw(self.screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

        # --- FPS ---

        clock.tick(20)

    # --- quit ---

    pygame.quit()

Game().run()
```

Comment: What is the question? or where is the error?

Comment: I need to add two randomization parameters specified under point 1 and 2. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: FWIW, I've been brushing up on [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), and have made a few files that use your `dot` shape, including some animations, because I like playing with optical illusion stuff. SVG is a vector-based format, so SVG drawings can be scaled & rotated without pixelization. And SVG files can be displayed in any (modern) Web browser. I'll paste a complete SVG file for a single dot in the next comment. To rotate it to a different orientation, just change the `45` in the `rotate(45,50,50)` command.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="M78.284,40 a30,30 0, 1,0 0,20 H50 v-20 Z" transform="rotate(45,50,50)"/></svg>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is the first time I get in touch with the pygame library, it might be that there is a better solution that this, but after a small research I think that the best way of detecting overlapping is by using the detection of pixel perfect collision on .png masks.That is, pygame allows checking a by-color overlapping of players by defining masks for them. I modified your code and it seems to work well now:

```
import random
import pygame

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0  ,0  ,0  )
RED = (255,0,0)

PLAYERS = []

class Player():

    def __init__(self, image, x=0, y=0):

        self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha() #.convert()
        #self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.centery = y


        #self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)


    #------------

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    #------------

    def update(self):
        #randomly rotate
        angle = random.randint(0,360)
        #self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.image, angle, 1)

        # here change randomly positon
        self.rect.topleft = random.randint(60,220+1), random.randint( 0, 475+1)
        searchAgain = 0
        while (searchAgain < 1):
            self.rect.topleft = random.randint(60,220+1), random.randint( 0, 475+1)
            searchAgain = 1

            for p in PLAYERS:
                # creating masks for the images
                myImage_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
                myOtherImage_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(p.image)

                # this is where the images are
                myImage_rect = self.rect
                myOtherImage_rect = p.rect

                # this is where we check for pixel perfect collision
                # observe the order mask variables are used in calculating offset and in overlap method
                offset_x, offset_y = (myOtherImage_rect.left - myImage_rect.left), (myOtherImage_rect.top - myImage_rect.top)
                print (offset_x, offset_y )
                if (myImage_mask.overlap(myOtherImage_mask, (offset_x, offset_y)) != None):
                    print 'Collision Detected!'

                    #if we detect collision of players stay in the loop so that we get another pair of coordinates for the new player
                    searchAgain = 0
                else:
                    print 'None'



class Game():

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

        self.background = pygame.image.load("background.jpg").convert()
        self.multi_players = []

        # create stimuli

        for i in range(1,10):
            player = Player("stim"+str(i)+".png")
            #player = Player("stim6.gif")
            player.update() # set random position on start
            PLAYERS.append(player)

            self.multi_players.append(player)

    #------------

    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        RUNNING = True

        while RUNNING:

            # --- events ---

            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    RUNNING = False

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        RUNNING = False

                    # changes position when key is pressed

                    for player in self.multi_players:
                        player.update()

            # --- updates ---- 

            # place for updates

            # --- draws ---

            self.screen.fill(WHITE)

            self.screen.blit(self.background, self.background.get_rect())

            for player in self.multi_players:
                player.draw(self.screen)

            pygame.display.flip()

            # --- FPS ---

            clock.tick(20)

        # --- quit ---

        pygame.quit()

Game().run()
```

The most of the changes is done in the update() function in the Player class, but in general, what I do is this:

1. I define a global list of players to which I add each newly created player
2. In each update I rotate the player first for a random angle
3. Then I give it a random x,y position
4. Afterwards I check if the newly created player will overlap with the existing ones in the PLAYERS list.And I do the checks via the masks comparison
5. If there is no collision - I add the player, if there is a collision - I ask for another set of random coordinates.

As for the pairs, I didn't quite understand if you need to create opposite pairs of dots or not, but in any case I hope that you will have enough to go on with what I posted here. You can get the full example here: [on my dropbox link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57571397/gametest.rar)

Hope it helps,
best regards,
Gazmend.

Also,as an addition, when using the transparent PNG files to avoid problems with having a black background after rotating a non-squared png images, simply comment the line self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK) in the code above.I am saying this, from personal expirience, it seems that when using PNG's, you do not need to take care for the transparency by defining the colorkey.

Comment: Gaijin has "9 images, each made of dot pairs, named with 'stim*.png'". Drawing the dot pairs in the program would make it more versatile, though.

Comment: Thanks, PM 2Ring,seems that some tab slipped in while copy-pasteing, I changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

I can not test this code with pygame for now because not installed on this computer, but for a theoric advise :

1) To avoid object overlapping. You should maintain a list of already placed items and verify when generating a random location that their bounding boxes are not overlapping.

An example could be

in `__init__` method add a `self.surfaces = []`

and then when drawing object add them to `self.surfaces`. Each time your generate an new random object, make this:

```
def test_overlapping_with_other_surfaces(self, myRandomlyPlacedImage):
    """ Tests if the randomly placed image overlap with an already existing image. """
    for surface in self.surface:
        if surface.get_rect.colliderect(myRandomlyPlacedImage.get_rect):
            return False
    return True
```

If the call to this function return false, randomly move the image to another location and test again.

2) The randomization of the orientation seems to be very simple. In fact, see the official documentation,http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate

```
def randomly_rotate_image(self, image):
    """ Returns the image randomly rotated. """
    angle = randint(0,360)
    return pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
```

And make use of  `self.randomly_rotate_image(image).clip()` instead of `image.clip()`

Hope it helps.

Arthur.